# How to control when a gridboard is generated?

Tags: rally, code-rally

I’m creating a list of features using a Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder and a rallygridboard to display the list.

I do however need to load additional data in the TreeStore, namely the predecessor and successor stores, in order to also display the content of these in the rallygridboard.

I can do this in the TreeStore load event, but when adding filters on the rallygridboard there is a problem with the order in which data is loaded and displayed.

So my question is, how do I do this?

- Can I “pause” any rallygridboard rendering/display until my decendents loads are performed in the TreeStore load event?
- Can I manually take control of the refresh of the rallygridboard, so that I need to fire a “render/display” event, when data is ready?

Thank you for all input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to probably just refresh the gridboard when you know all of your subsequent stores have been loaded.  Something like this?

```
gridBoard.getGridOrBoard().getView().refresh();
```

Treestores and the gridboard in general can be fairly clumsy to work with and customize unfortunately.  There's just really a ton of complexity there.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the trick that made my app work. I don't know how much time I've spent trying to fix this - trying to find the correct function for the refresh!

Question: Apart from http://developer.rallydev.com are there any in-depth resources or through examples that I can look at? I'm looking at other projects, but it seems that many different approaches are used.

Comment: This does refresh the grid, but it doesn't call my custom rendering functions in the Grid. Why is this?